# Get Today date using Jquery Full Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery "Fullcalender.js" file version (FullCalendar v2.2.5)
I have one dive in may .aspx page

```
<div id="jweek"></div>
```

In this div i want to display today's date in format

```
2020-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

Here is my jquery code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#jweek').fullCalendar('today');
        });    
    </script>
```

Code for Dynamic Checkbox list

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var checkedvalue = [];
         $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetRole",

            data: '',
            //data: JSON.stringify(obj),

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {

                var json = JSON.parse(data.d);

                var val = 0;

                var table = $('<table></table>');

                var option = json.map(x =>

                    table.append($('<tr></tr>').append($('<td></td>').append($('<input>').attr({

                        type: 'checkbox', name: 'chkRoles', value: x.chkName, id: 'chkrole' + val

                    }))).append(

                        $('<label>').attr({

                            for: 'chkRoles' + val++

                        }).text(x.chkName))));



                $('#chkrole').append(table);

            }

        });

        $("#btnget").click(function () {

            checkedvalue = [];

            $("input[name=chkRoles]").each(function () {

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                    checkedvalue.push($(this).val());

                }

            });

            $("#lblSelected").text(checkedvalue);

        });


    });

</script>
```

So as you can see in above dynamic checkbox list i want to pass the current date of calender and based on that i want to generate checkbox list for next 7 days. I hope my question is clear and sorry for my english 
Here is my web method in which i want to pass current calender date so can go though loop

```
 [WebMethod()]
// Get current select date from calender and generate next 7 days inside the //checkbox
        public static string GetRole()
         {
//Use the date which is passed
            DateTime today = '';
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

            dt.Columns.Add("chkName", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {

            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to format your date but you cannot able to?

Comment: @hasan05 sir when i run the page date is not display as well as i want the date in above format as well

Comment: any console error?

Comment: @hasan05 no sir nothing display in console as well can you give me idea or any other way to display current date in div

Answer (score 1):

You can Get the today date with simple javascript code below :-

```
 var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
alert(output);
```

Currently I stored the current date value in "Output" variable. you can put the value as per your requirement.

Comment: you are right but my whole project is depend on FullCalender in which when i click on the next or previous button from calender i want to update my dynamic checkbox list here i need to pass the current date of my calender in to some place i am updating my code please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
var custom_format= $('#YourCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var calDate = custom_format.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'); //Here you can format your Date
```

Comment: Varma Lanke not sir it showing me message [Object Object]